# How to use Best in place with nested association in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, best-in-place

app/models/user.rb

```
has_one :user_detail
```

app/models/user_detail.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

`unit_number` is attribute of user_detail.

I want to edit inline this attribute in user show page.But I can't understand how I do it.

```
<%= best_in_place user, :unit_number %>
```

It gives an error.How I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<%= best_in_place user.user_detail, :unit_number, path: user_detail_path %>
```

Where `user_detail_path` is the update user detail path. You have to define this routes from routes.rb.

Comment: in this there is one if user.user_detail is nil then it gives error...I want that if user.user_detail is nil then show 0 and user can edit it?Is it possible?

Comment: undefined method `user_detail_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fa2159d0b20>:0x007fa21523e420>

Comment: Is there any configuration for user_details resource?

Comment: Is there user_details controller?

Comment: No as such no controller

Comment: So you have to configure routes to update user_details and change the route path in the codebase.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105358/discussion-between-haseeb-ahmad-and-ganesh-kunwar).